# Covert string into a vector of letter in R

Tags: r, string, vectorization

Suppose I have a string in R as `"aa1122ddccdsadsa"`

I want to convert any string into a vector of letters, how can I do that ?

I mean give an string, I want to it be

```
"a" "a" "1" "1" "2" etc
```

Comment: `strsplit("aa1122ddccdsadsa", "")[[1]]`

Answer (score 0):

There are actually lots of ways to do this. Here's one using `strsplit` and regex:

```
x <- c("aa1122ddccdsadsa")

strsplit(gsub("([[:alnum:]]{1})", "\\1 ", x), " ")[[1]]

> strsplit(gsub("([[:alnum:]]{1})", "\\1 ", x), " ")[[1]]
 [1] "a" "a" "1" "1" "2" "2" "d" "d" "c" "c" "d" "s" "a" "d" "s" "a"
```

You could also use `substring` or `plyr`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `stri_sub` function from [stringi package](http://stringi.rexamine.com)
Get substrings of length 1 from 1,2,3... letter

```
require(stringi)    
x <- "alamakota"
stri_sub(x,from=1:stri_length(x),length = 1)
## [1] "a" "l" "a" "m" "a" "k" "o" "t" "a"
```